# Extending MultiSelect widget breaks value binding in MVVM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mvvm, kendo-ui

I extended the multiselect widget with nothing special. The issue is the binding of values no longer work. In a first sample, I'm using the native widget and binds values fine. The second is where I use an extended multiselect which fails on the value binding and is blank.

HTML:

```
<selectdata-role="multiselect"data-bind="source: selectData, value: selectedIDs"data-text-field="Name"data-value-field="ID"></select>
<selectdata-role="multiselectcustom"data-bind="source: selectData, value: selectedIDs"data-text-field="Name"data-value-field="ID"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
//EXTEND MULTISELECT WITH NOTHING MUCH
kendo.ui.plugin(kendo.ui.MultiSelect.extend({
    init: function(element, options) {
        kendo.ui.MultiSelect.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
    },
    options: {
        name: 'MultiSelectCustom'
    }
}));

varviewModel = kendo.observable({
    selectedIDs: [ 1, 3 ],
    selectData: [{
        Name: 'Bill Smith',
        ID: 1
    }, {
        Name: 'Jennifer Jones',
        ID: 2
    }, {
        Name: 'Tim Philips',
        ID: 3
    }]
});

kendo.bind('body', viewModel);
```

[image]

I guess I can re-create the binder for "value" again, but is this indeed a bug? I have a jsFiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/basememara/2Dacw/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this isn't a bug so much as that multiselect has custom binders set for it. You can try duplicating the binders for the multiselect for your new extended role.

try this:

```
 kendo.data.binders.widget.multiselectcustom = kendo.data.binders.widget.multiselect;
```

you can place it before/after your widget extension code, but this *should* tell the bind function how to properly bind to your widget.

I would also take a look at the kendo docs for custom binders, be warned though it isn't very thourough

Comment: Shouldn't extending bring forth everything associated? You would expect the binders to work. Clean workaround though. Do this have to be done for all extended widgets?

Comment: i share that sentiment, i think it should but what can you do? You could extend the extend method of kendo.ui.Widget to work that way, but i never tested that.

you don't need to do it for every extended widget just the ones that have special-per-widget bindings, which thus far is only the multiselect. you can see what I mean by looking at the kendo.data.binders.widget, and see that there is only multiselect, that is specific. Internally kendo checks first for binders specific to the widget role, then widget namespace in general

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Kendo support didn't acknowledge it as a bug so I'm trying to convince them otherwise. For the meantime, you're workaround is clean and works great!! http://jsfiddle.net/basememara/2Dacw/10/

Comment: no problem, this drove me crazy for a while, glad to help ease the pain